# Bash script to start 'motion' on screen lock

Tags: bash, lock-screen

I wish to write a bash script that executes on start up Ubuntu 13.04 and starts `motion` whenever the screen is locked. Being a novice at bash scripting, I wasn't able to understand the various help sources available on the web and thereby write a script on my own. Anyways, I know that the following command is used to check if the system is locked:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active"
```

But, if I use this command, I will have to periodically (say every 5-10 seconds) check the lock status. Is there a better alternative? Could someone provide me with a skeleton of the script?

So I could write the following script which starts the webcam once I lock the screen but does not stop it once sign back in. Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    sleep 2
    if (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active");
    then
        motion 2> ~/.motion/log
    elif (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is inactive");
    then
        /etc/init.d/motion stop 1> /dev/null
    fi
done
```

Comment: You can use `sleep 5` to wait 5 seconds before you check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can find a simple better alternative at `gnome-screensaver-command -q` command, but I found a solution to make your script to function as probably you expect:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

is_active=0

while :
do
    sleep 2
    if (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active");
    then
        if [ "$is_active" -eq "0" ];
        then
            is_active=1
            motion 2> ~/.motion/log &
        fi
    elif (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is inactive");
    then
        if [ "$is_active" -eq "1" ];
        then
            is_active=0
            /etc/init.d/motion stop 1> /dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

Some explanation:

- `motion 2> ~/.motion/log` command followed by `&` will start the `motion` process to run in terminal; without `&`, when the execution of the script reach to that line, this will remain hanged/blocked there.
- you don't need to run at every 2 seconds `motion 2> ~/.motion/log &` or `/etc/init.d/motion stop 1> /dev/null` command, but only when the state of the screensaver is changing; for this reason other changes from the script.

Answer (score 2):

`gnome-screensaver` emits some signals on dbus when something happens.

The following line, when run, prints a line whenever the screen is locked or unlocked:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'"
```

On my machine, the following is printed **when the screen is locked**:

```
signal sender=:1.87 -> dest=(null destination) serial=20 path=/org/gnome/ScreenSaver; interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver; member=ActiveChanged
   boolean true
```

And **when unlocked**, the following text is printed:

```
signal sender=:1.87 -> dest=(null destination) serial=22 path=/org/gnome/ScreenSaver; interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver; member=ActiveChanged
   boolean false
```

---

## Script to lock screen and start motion

To make use of this, we run the above command in the script and whenever something is printed we check if it was a screen lock or screen unlock action.

```
#! /bin/bash

function onScreenLock() {
    motion 2> ~/.motion/log &
}

function onScreenUnlock() {
    /etc/init.d/motion stop 1> /dev/null
}

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | 
( 
    while true; 
    do 
        read X; 
        if echo $X | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; 
        then 
            onScreenLock(); 
        elif echo $X | grep "boolean false" &> /dev/null; 
        then 
            onScreenUnlock(); 
        fi
    done 
)
```

***Source and further information:***

- [***Unix Stack Exchange*** - Run Script on screen lock/unlock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28183)
- [***Gnome Documentation*** - gnome-screensaver](http://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html#gs-signals)